# Business Objects Login failed while using SDK

Tags: java, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am migrating a BI3.X API application to **BI4.1**. The purpose of the application is to retrieve PDF reports from SAP BOE.

I have referred few documents and was able to make it using Opendoc URL. But I only receive HTML as response in opendoc URL. So I decided to go with SDK to retrieve PDF as response..

I am facing problem while logging on to the application using SDK. The BOE cluster name is accessible from web browser but I am not able to ping it.

Earlier I was getting token for the opendoc using secLDAP authentication with below URL
http://server.domain.com:6405/biprws/logon/long

The code I am using now:

```
ISessionMgr sessionMgr = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession = 
       sessionMgr.logon("username", "password", "server.domain.com:6405", "secEnterprise");
String sessionToken = enterpriseSession.getLogonTokenMgr().getDefaultToken();
```

While running above code I get the following error message.
Not able to connect CMS. Specify the correct host and port and check for network issues.

I tried to see the problem.
http://server.domain.com/BOE/BI is accessible
but when I try to ping server.domain.com, it is not reachable.

Any idea what should I do now ? I am still not sure how this works as I am new to SAP environment.
I am not even sure if I should use the same server name which I used with opendoc.

Comment: You're trying to connect to port `6405`, which is the WACS server by default. Are you sure that a WACS server is active and that it has the BOE web app deployed to it? Check if you can connect to `http://server.domain.com:6405/BOE/BI`. Also, is there a reason why you'd use the Java SDK over the REST SDK? The latter is actively being developed, while the Java SDK seems like it will be deprecated in future versions (the REBEAN SDK is already deprecated).

Comment: I have tried using REST web calls but couldn't get hold of the URL structure to retrieve PDF. For instance one of the report I need is My Report.rpt which has URL http://server:6405/biprws/infostore/61915 , I am not sure about the URL to get parameters and the url which I have to submit to get PDF. I have CUID of the reports as well which has to br retrieved. As I am stuck here and not many people here to help me on migration, I thought of java SDK.

Comment: And another reason is I am not sure if Opendoc is a feasible solution for an application with vast users as we have to assign a token for every user who wants to access report. I tried to reuse the same token for multiple users but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the outformat with **opendocument URL**. Just add the parameter `sOutputFormat`. Possible values are:

- H: HTML
- P : PDF
- E : Excel (Crystal Reports only)
- W : RTF (Crystal Reports only)

So you will have the following URL:
*http://server:port/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?iDocID=AZuIwjRPI2BApS7VCZMFpNs&sIDType=CUID&**sOutputFormat=P***

You can also use the docId if you don't have the cuid
*http://server:port/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?iDocID=5676&sOutputFormat=P*

OpenDocument URL documentation is available here: https://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41_opendocument_en.pdf

For exporting rep file in PDF format **with the REST API**, you have to use the following URI:
*http:///infostore//rpt/export?mime_type=application/pdf*

Crystal Reports RESTful documentation is available here: *http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp3_cr_restws_en.pdf*